# Mandatory file locking in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, file, bash, unix

According to a `man` pages the following approaches supports only advisory locking: `flock`, `lockf` and `fcntl`. Is there any way to mandatory lock a some file by a single process, for example with a write lock, so that other process will not able to open this file with the write permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Operating systems in the Unix family do not generally support mandatory file locking<sup>1</sup>.  This includes Linux, BSD, and OS X.

On some Unixes, you are prevented from opening files for writing if they are executable images that are currently running; `open()` will fail with `ETXTBSY`.  However, you can always just unlink (delete) the file and create a new one instead, and nothing will prevent that.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>: This is not entirely true, but mandatory file locks require a bit of work, mandatory locks are platform-specific, and OS X has no support for them.

Comment: My current research confirm it too.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) still does not support mandatory locking on files (for example, by setting the mode to 2644), unlike some other systems.  Mandatory file locking is not required by POSIX, but was supported on SVR4 systems.