# How can I ensure I can read the file and its not locked by another process

Tags: c++, c, macos

My environment is Mac OS X and my program is in C++
If a process A is accessing a file in such a way that other processes will be denied read access to that file.
Then my process B tries to open the file using C/C++ function fopen with "rb" mode.

Should I expect fopen to fail and return null ? or will fopen possibly succeed but read call will fail ?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: How about creating 2 program and trying yourself?

Comment: I do not know, what possible ways are there to prevent other processes from accessing the file, I want to know what should be the behaviour of fopen will it change or be the same in all cases..

Comment: Upon successful completion, fopen() returns a pointer to the object controlling the stream. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.Please have a look http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fopen.html

Comment: If a function may fail, you should expect it to fail. Why worry about this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Beej's Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/flocking.html)

Read also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603684/mandatory-file-locking-in-mac-os-x), seems that mandatory locks (what you are looking for) are platform-specific, and OS X has no support for them.