# Preventing opening file twice from different processes

Tags: c++, c, macos, file-locking

After a research I made, I'm still not sure if there are APIs that allows you to open file exclusively, meaning, any other process would not be able to right to the file.
Please can someone give me a good reference/guide/note/manual that covers this topic?
Thanks a lot!

Edit: Advisory Locking is good enough.

Comment: You mean "exclusively", not "excessively", right?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603684/mandatory-file-locking-in-mac-os-x).

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ libraries (i.e. `std::[io]fstream`, `fopen`) which supports this.  At the system level, it depends on the system: Windows does, Unix doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

There are three primary systems for file locking between processes:

- [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
- [`lockf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lockf.html)
- [`flock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/flock)

Some Unix-like systems might not have `flock()`; they might have `lockf()` instead, for example, or they might only have `fcntl()` locking (though most will have both `lockf()` and `fcntl()` and many will have `flock()` too).  The current version of POSIX mandates `fcntl()` locking and `lockf()` locking for file-level inter-process locking.  (POSIX also defines [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html), `funlockfile()` and `ftrylockfile()` — which are used for controlling locking between threads in an application).

AFAIK, you can implement both `lockf()` and `flock()` locking using `fcntl()` locking.

Note that the locking functions work on file descriptors or file streams.  Each program will be able to open the file, but will then apply advisory locking calls to check whether it has exclusive access to the file.

Note that some systems support mandatory file locking (indicated by setting the setgid bit on a file while the corresponding group execute bit is not set — so 2644 mode, for example).  However, Mac OS X does not support mandatory locking (10.10 Yosemite tested, but prior versions also have this limitation).  POSIX does not require mandatory locking support.  It was provided on SVR4 systems.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent file reading from multiple processess, all of them must implement the same locking mechanism.

One way would be using `flock` mechanism, which is not available everywhere. From `flock(2)` manpage:

```
CONFORMING TO
    4.4BSD (the flock() call first appeared in 4.2BSD).
    A version of flock(), possibly implemented in terms of fcntl(2),
    appears on most UNIX systems.
```

Another way would be using a *lockfile* -- file alongside the original one indicating the lock is active. C11 specifies a modifier `x` to mode in [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), which ensures that the file is always created and not opened if it already exists:

```
FILE * f = fopen("filename.lock", "wx");
if (!f) {
    // File already exists!
    return 0;
}

// Do stuff
fclose(f);
remove("filename.lock");
```

Comment: What do you mean flock is not available everywhere?

Comment: @Sanich It is not part of C/C++ standard, so it is environment-specific. See added `flock(2)` manpage snippet

Comment: @Sanich: some Unix-like systems might not have `flock()`; they might have `lockf()` instead, for example, or they might only have `fcntl()` locking.  The current version of POSIX mandates `fcntl()` locking and `lockf()` locking (and also `flockfile()`, `funlockfile()` and `ftrylockfile()` — which I only came across just now; they're used for controlling locking between threads in an application).  AFAIK, you can implement both `lockf()` and `flock()` locking using `fcntl()` locking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting functions, I didn't know that `lockf(3)` acquires mandatory lock.

Comment: AFAICT, `lockf()` only applies mandatory locks on files with the appropriate mandatory locking permissions (setgid bit set, group execute bit reset) on systems that support mandatory locking.  POSIX does not require support for mandatory locking.  SVR4 (Unix System V Release 4) did provide mandatory locking, and systems derived from that (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, …) probably still support it.